# Where are save files located?

Tags: prison-architect

Since Steam Cloud support isn't implemented yet, we still have to move the save file around if we move computers, so where are they located?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an option in the main menu "Open saves folder".

Comment: Will that open it in the file browser?

Comment: Yes, that will open the folder in the file browser.  (At least on windows, but I can't imagine that it would not work on the other platforms)

Comment: Nitpicky thing perhaps, but this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 31):

### Prison Architect Save Locations

#### Linux

```
~/.Prison Architect/saves/
```

#### Mac

```
~/Library/Application Support/Prison Architect/saves/
```

#### Windows

```
C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\AppData\Local\Introversion\Prison Architect\saves\
```

---

**Note:**

- **~** denotes the home directory of your user.

Comment: This seems to work, but does not unlock campaigns and cut scenes. For this the 'Campaigns' folder, and 'unlocked.txt' needs to be copied as well.

Comment: That `C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\...` location don't work for steam it almost don't work shows only 1 of my 17 saves

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Prison Architect Wiki](http://prisonarchitectwiki.com/wiki/Home), the save file is located at

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Introversion\Prison Architect\saves