# My prison won't receive any food from deliveries and it says my prisoners won't come for 10,000 hours

Tags: prison-architect

I only have one prisoner left for some reason and it says that the 9 prisoners won't come for 16,689 hours, I tried to open than close the prison intake and also went into the save and changed it into continuous and it still didn't work. Food also isn't being delivered and I made two deliveries and it didn't work. Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: your save is corrupted, just start a new prison

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fix the next intake problem and see if that resolves the food deliveries (it's not going to deliver food when there are no prisoners to eat it).

Find your [save game file](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126202/where-are-save-files-located) and open it in a text editor. in the top section of the file you are looking for two values `TimeIndex` and `Intake.next`; edit the `Intake.next` value to be 100 more than `TimeIndex`. That should resolve the time to next intake issue.

Reload the save game and see, after the new prisoners have arrived, if you start to receive food deliveries again.